# Object within a hashtable

Tags: object, powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to put objects in a hashtable. I'm not getting errors but cannot access the data.

```
$Level1Hashtable = @{}
$Level2Object = New-Object System.Object
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value "abc"
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpAddress -Value "192.168.1.1"
$Level1Hashtable.Add("Test1",$Level2Object)
$Level2Object = New-Object System.Object
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value "123"
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpAddress -Value "192.168.1.1"
$Level1Hashtable.Add("Test2",$Level2Object)

$Level1Hashtable.Test1.IpAddress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works for me using V4.  Running in V2 it doesn't work, but does if I switch from using System.Object to PSObject for the object type in the New-Object cmdlets.

```
$Level1Hashtable = @{}
$Level2Object = New-Object PSObject
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value "abc"
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpAddress -Value "192.168.1.1"
$Level1Hashtable.Add("Test1",$Level2Object)
$Level2Object = New-Object PSObject
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value "123"
$Level2Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IpAddress -Value "192.168.1.1"
$Level1Hashtable.Add("Test2",$Level2Object)

$Level1Hashtable.Test1.IpAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of redundant instantiation doesn't really impress me, so I went a slightly different route:

```
$Servers =
@{
    "DC1" = [pscustomobject]@{ FQDN = "dc1.ad.foobar.com"; IpAddress = "192.168.2.1"}
    "DC2" = [pscustomobject]@{ FQDN = "dc2.ad.foobar.com"; IpAddress = "192.168.2.2"}
    "STS" = [pscustomobject]@{ FQDN = "sts.ad.foobar.com"; IpAddress = "192.168.2.3"}
}
```

Then you can also access elements very easily:

```
Servers["DC1"].IpAddress = "192.168.2.4"
```

Tested on PowerShell Core (aka PowerShell 6), works like a charm. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of PowerShell you're using Add-Member had an issue (v1 and maybe v2) where you had to use -PassThru and reassign to the original object e.g.:

```
$Level2Object = $Level2Object | Add-Member NoteProperty Name abc -PassThru
```

In V3 you can create this more simply like so:

```
$Level2Object = [pscustomobject]@{Name='abc';IpAddress='192.168.1.1'}
```

In V2 you can use the `Property` parameter on new-object to simplify as well:

```
$Level2Object = new-object psobject -property @{Name='abc';IpAddress='192.168.1.1'}
```